# Wrong path using require_once

Tags: php, require-once

I have a problem tring to use require_once.
I am specifying a wrong path and I can't find a solution.

I have a file named header.php that includes two files by using require_once: functions.php and navigation.php.
This part is working fine. 
The problem appears when I try to include header.php in a file named view.php located in a different directory.

here is the arborescence:

```
C:\wamp\www\1.1\plugins\docreader\php\view.php
C:\wamp\www\1.1\theme\dark-blue\templates\files\header.inc.php
C:\wamp\www\1.1\theme\dark-blue\templates\files\functions.inc.php
C:\wamp\www\1.1\theme\dark-blue\templates\files\navigation.inc.php
```

I tried a lot of different paths but without any success.

Do someone have a clue please ?

Comment: You just need a little bit of  [`MAGIC`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: so glad my php days are over xD

Answer (score 1):

Read about (and use) the magic constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and function [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to generate the path of the included file starting from the path of the includer.

For example, if in `plugins\docreader\php\view.php` you want to include `theme\dark-blue\templates\files\functions.inc.php` then use something like this:

```
// Use this in 'plugins\docreader\php\view.php'
include dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))).
        '/theme/dark-blue/templates/files/functions.inc.php';
```

`__DIR__` is a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) that evaluates to the directory that contains the file where it is used. In `C:\wamp\www\1.1\plugins\docreader\php\view.php`, the value of `__DIR__` is `'C:\wamp\www\1.1\plugins\docreader\php'`.

The function [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) returns the parent directory of the provided path. Kind of `..`, only better. Using it three times reduces the value passed as argument (the value of `__DIR__` explained above) to `'C:\wamp\www\1.1'`. Everything is straight forward from there: add the relative path to the desired file (`'/theme/dark-blue/templates/files/functions.inc.php'`) and forget about inclusion problems.

Comment: thank you for beiing that prompt to answer . I tried what you suggested but it isn't working.  I think the problem comes from the fact that header.php includes itself two other files. header.php is the one I'm trying to include in view.php.  I tried to include the two others  in view.php but the problem is still there.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant SITE_TEMPLATES_PATH - assumed 'SITE_TEMPLATES_PATH' in C:\wamp\www\1.1\theme\dark-blue\templates\files\header.inc.php on line 3
Warning: require_once(SITE_TEMPLATES_PATH/files/functions.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\1.1\theme\dark-blue\templates\files\header.inc.php on line 3
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'SITE_TEMPLATES_PATH/files/functions.inc.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\1.1\theme\dark-blue\templates\files\header.inc.php on line 3

Comment: line 3 is : require_once(SITE_TEMPLATES_PATH . '/files/functions.inc.php');

Comment: I only gave you an example. I don't know which file you need to include and where. Just use the idea in all your `include`/`require` (in the included files too) and it will work.

Comment: yes, I made my brain work a little and this is what I did. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your file paths absolute rather than relative. A useful super global for achieving this is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which will evaluate to your web server file root.