# Define absolute path for PHP-include

Tags: php

I'm currently using this method to include certain parts for my HTML-Template:

`<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/common.php"; ?>`.
Which until now works fine for me, but there is only one problem. My main domain (let's call it test.com for this example) is attached to the root folder. But my subdomain is attached to another folder. So it would look like this:

`test.com | /var/www/Root Folder`

`sub1.test.com | /var/www/Root Folder/Subdomains/Essentials/Sub1`

So that means that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` would not work properly because the root virtual changed. I know that you can use: `<?php include_once '/var/www/Root Folder/common.php'; ?>`. But that's a pain, because if I move my website to another server, than I have to change the absolute path again.

Are there any solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it possible to solve it using the `__DIR__` constant?

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` does not help because many times the server uses path aliases.

Comment: If being able to move it is a requirement, the file should be part of the code-base of the sub-domain app and you should not link to another app or site to include it. So you could copy it, make it available as a component through composer, etc.

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36112325/4265352), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29437160/4265352) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35033901/4265352) on similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I would suggest using the `__DIR__` constant or `dirname(__FILE__)`, which is for older versions of PHP, as outlined by Justinas in a comment below.

`__DIR__` essentially defines the directory that the file that is processing is currently in.  So, if your script is in the same directory, you would put something like:

`index.php is in  __DIR__`

and if sub1.test.com needs to include something in the root directory, and you're in the subdomains, essentials, etc.... you would do:

`include_once(__DIR__ . "/../../../common.php")`

This would traverse back 3 directories, to the Root Directory, and include the file.

Comment: For older php: `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: Thanks @Justinas, I'll update my answer.

Comment: That looks great. But that would mean that if I add another subdomain on top of the sub1 folder, than it needs to travel back 4 directories, right?

Comment: @CodeGeekBot ../ goes to the parent directory